# How to sleep forever only using C++11

Tags: c++11

Yes, I could use Sleep() in Windows or pause() in POSIX, and goes on.
But how do I sleep only using C++11? I thought there was a way, which is joining calling thread using std::this_thread but std::this_thread has no join() method unlike pthread functions.
Not to mention that we can't handle signals with C++11 and I know how to iterate sleep forever like below:

```
while(true)
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

However, as you can see, It's not elegant at all. This code still consumes CPU time. The scheduler has to care for this process. I could also use conditional variable or promise, but then again it takes up a bit of memory or wouldn't work on certain OS(it would throw an exception to avoid deadlock).

Maybe this could be the equivalent of Sleep(INFINITE) of Windows:

```
while(true)
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours::max());
```

But many say it's not practical.

Could anyone think of brilliant way?

Comment: sleep_until with a none-reachable time seems more logic to me for `sleeping forever`

Comment: You could block on a locked mutex?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This feels like an XY question...

Comment: There's no reason to provide such ting in standard, as standard doesn't provide anything that interrupts infinite sleep (eg. signals).

Comment: If you're worried about the CPU usage of a `while(true) sleep(1)` solution, just change the `1` into an `86400`. Waking up for a few milliseconds a day shouldn't be *too* onerous.

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility:

```
std::promise<void>().get_future().wait();
```

Or if you prefer:

```
std::promise<void> p;
p.get_future().wait();
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways I can think of.

One, which @Guiroux mentions is to `sleep_until` a non-reachable time:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::hours(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()));
```

Or have it wait indefinitely for a condition that will never be fulfilled.

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
cv.wait(lock, []{return false;});
```

However I can't see a reason for this.

Comment: Is there a risk that adding the maximum limit hours to `now()` overflows the parameter type so that a `time_point` in the past is given to `sleep_until`? That scenario was discussed for gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58038

Comment: I just used that to create a really big number in the future.

Comment: Sure, but since you _add_ that big number to `now()`, I wonder if the _sum_ can overflow, wrap around, and result in an actual `time_point` that was _before_ `now()`.

Comment: Sure it's fine _now_ but how long does it take before `now()` gets too big, if ever? :-)

Comment: (hint: the math is trivial-ish, but I'm on the run and can't really do it in my head) :-)

Comment: Some OSes do not allow that to happen("deadlock prevented"). The process would just crash. It was not a good question anyway, so.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to calculate a time, why not sleep until the system's maximum representable time?

```
std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>::max());
```

Comment: This fails on Visual C++ 2017. It seems to overflow somewhere.

Comment: @isanae:  What about std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::system_clock::duration::max())?
(VS2015 turns this into a call to sleep_until() - does VS2017?)

Comment: Nope. `sleep_for()` forwards to `sleep_until()`, which converts the `time_point` to absolute time by adding it to `now()`, which overflows. I don't think that's the way to go at all. Waiting on a `condition_variable` like in Graham's answer seems to be the best solution.

Comment: [I've asked about the behaviour of large values in `sleep_*()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42638847/4885801) and it would appear that this is a defect in Visual C++. It works fine on libstdc++ and libc++.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking forward to hear why simply double-locking a nonrecursive mutex is bad, assuming that you really do want to sleep forever:

```
std::mutex m;
m.lock();
m.lock();
```

No unnecessary wakeups, termination protocol still works.
This creates quite *a lot* less code than using `std::promise<void>().get_future().wait();`.

Comment: Double-locking a nonrecursive mutex results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a good point. The fact that it's UB, however, is not.

Comment: @Jeremy what about std::unique_lock l(m), l2(m);?

Comment: @Arsen Zahray - Still UB.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock item (3).