# Blocking eternally on Unix

Tags: unix, portability

I have a process that does nothing, it just needs to exist to stop a process group ID being reallocated to a new process.

I'm doing this, but wonder if there's a more canonical way to eternally sleep:

```rust
loop {
    sleep(60 * 60 * 24 * SECOND);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sleep forever only using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711131/how-to-sleep-forever-only-using-c11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pause()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the pointer @darnir!